# blink text in css using hover() jquery

Tags: jquery, css

for at first I don't know how to make a good title for this problem. You can know the problem better by seeing the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/5Cz5D/

when I hover the img, the text appeared but then I move my cursor over the text, it became blink..

I used the following jQuery snippet to prevent it from flickering, but no luck.

```
$(".profilePicture").hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this).next('a');
    $this.show();
}, function () {
    var $this = $(this).next('a');
    $this.hide();
});
```

Comment: A question should contain sufficient code and explanations to reproduce the problem. A jsfiddle is fine, but not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No jQuery necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/5Cz5D/1/

```
.profilePicture:hover + .percent, .percent:hover {display: block;}
```

Comment: @RickiVandenbroek it means: every `.percent` that directly follows `.profilePicture` in the HTML structure. (And `.profilePicture` has to be hovered.) For more on these selectors, take a look here: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: @RickiVandenbroek If this is the correct answer, please mark it as such by clicking the "wink".

Answer (score 2):

You have specified the `percentage` class outside the `profile_picture` div..

You can solve the problem by nesting `percentage` class inside the `profile_picture` div.

**[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Cz5D/3/)**